# meaning of let loose in the following sentence

Tags: meaning

I don't understand the meaning of **let loose** used in the following sentence

> It is a feel-good genie **let loose** every year during the British summer, while cricket provides an echo from Lord’s and other grounds across England.

[Link](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/break-from-tradition-the-hindu-editorial-on-wimbledon-cancellation/article31241312.ece?homepage=true)

Comment: **Let loose** means to give someone complete freedom and allow them to do what they wish. But I'm not sure if it's the intended meaning in the context you've given. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "genie" is a metaphor for the Tennis competition at Wimbledon.

In "let loose" means the same as "set free".  In Aladdin, the Genie is let loose from the lamp, and then performs magic tasks.  In England, Wimbledon is like a genie that is let loose and makes people feel good every summer.

The metaphor is extended in the next paragraph "Wimbledon uncorked its magic..."

Comment: It's from an editorial in _The Hindu_.

Answer (score -2):

**Let loose** means to relax and have fun. Usually after a period of time spent working or being serious.

I believe in that context: every year during summer time, the genie relaxes and has fun. The genie can hear crickets while relaxing during the summer.

Comment: Ha Ha,  Not "crickets" but "cricket"  The thwack of leather on willow, the shouts of "howzat" and the clink of fine china teacups and cucumber sandwiches with the crusts cut off. The Genie is a metaphor.

Comment: ...and Lord's is a famous cricket ground!

Comment: ...Stands the Church clock at ten to three? And is there honey still for tea?

Comment: @JamesK Ah! Fine china teacups with the crusts cut off and the clink of cucumber sandwiches! (_the clink of [fine china teacups and cucumber sandwiches] with the crusts cut off_)

Comment: The first sentence is fine but needs references. The second sentence is dubious and should be removed unless you can find references to back it up. The second paragraph is incorrect speculation and should be removed.